# Camel, end rest-based route, returning from choice in loop

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-rest

I'm trying to add error handling to my parallel processing:

```java
...
.multicast(new GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy())
.parallelProcessing()
  .to("direct:getAndSaveRoute1")
  .to("direct:getAndSaveRoute2")
.end()
.split(body())
  .choice()
    .when(simple("${body.errorOcurred} == true"))
      //TODO:: end route returning current body
    .endChoice()
    .otherwise()
      .log(...)
    .endChoice()
  .end()
//after split, if no error occurred
.to("direct:nextRoute")
.end()
```

I can't seem to figure out though how to return/ end the route (and pass back the current body as the rest response body) within the `choice` in the `split`. `end()` and `endRest()` seem to cause issues...

It is also not clear as how many `end()`s I need; Adding an `end()` for the split causes an exception and makes Spring fail to boot.

Comment: Have you tried using `.stop()` ?

Comment: Yep, did that with no change

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future, I ended up making a bean to turn the list into a single message, and then do a `choice` based on that.

Not very 'camel', but needed to be wrapped up